# How to get all values for a certain field in django ORM?

Tags: python, django

I have a table called `user_info`. I want to get names of all the users. So the table has a field called `name`. So in sql I do something like

```
SELECT distinct(name) from user_info
```

But I am not able to figure out how to do the same in django. Usually if I already have certain value known, then I can do something like below.

```
user_info.objects.filter(name='Alex')
```

And then get the information for that particular user.

But in this case for the given table, I want to get all the name values using django ORM just like I do in sql.

Here is my django model

```
class user_info(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    org = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

How can I do this in django?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `values_list`.

```
user_info.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
```

Note, in Python classes are usually defined in InitialCaps: your model should be UserInfo.

Comment: Sorry @daniel, i understand it's a long time. But, doing this for a model that has company names in it, i got just integers. Sort of: `<QuerySet [11, 14, 11]>` instead than `Google, Apple, Tesla`. Any idea for the reason why?

Comment: @Carlo.  It looks like your query set is returning the FK to another model that does not have a def __str__  set.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `values_list()` as given in Daniel's answer, which will provide you your data in a list containing the values in the field. Or you can also use, `values()` like this:

```
user_info.object.values('name')
```

which will return you a queryset containing a dictionary. `values_list()` and `values()` are used to select the columns in a table.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the accepted answer, if the field is a foreign key the id values(numerical) are returned in the queryset. Hence if you are expecting other kinds of values defined in the model of which the foreign key is part then you have to modify the query like this:

```
    `Post.objects.values_list('author__username')`
```

*Post* is a model class having *author* as a foreign key field which in turn has its *username* field:
Here, "author" field was **appended with double undersocre followed by the field "name"**, otherwise primary key of the model will be returned in queryset. I assume this was @Carlo's doubt in accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my blazing speed way of getting it! ;)

```
names_list = list(
    UserInfo.objects.distinct().order_by('name').values_list('name', flat=True)
)
```

Comment: can you substantiate the "blazing speed" statement in any way? And why is that necessary to state at all?

Comment: Man... I believe you had a bad day today. Please watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjPgdhRsGIQ&ab_channel=MasoodBoomgaard

Tell me a faster, more efficient way of getting this out of your database and I will downgrade my comment to "here's one way of doing it". :)